# Не отрисовывается изображение в окне Pygame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Есть два файла вот код первого:

```
import pygame
import sys
from gun import Gun


def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption('title')
    bg_color = (0,0,0)
    gun = Gun(screen)   

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    screen.fill(bg_color)
    gun.output()
    pygame.display.flip()

run()
```

И вот код второго файла:

```
import pygame

class Gun():
    
    def __init__(self, screen):
        """Инициализация пушки..."""

        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def output(self):
        """ Рисует пушку """ 
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

проблема в том что он ни как не хочет отрисовывать эту "пушку", можете сказать в чем проблема?

"Пушка" если что белого цвета, а фон черного

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что код для отрисовки "пушки", заливки экрана и смены дисплея не помещён в основной цикл игры - `while True`. Внесите эти строчки кода в основной цикл и всё заработает:

```py
import pygame
import sys
from gun import Gun


def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption('title')
    bg_color = (0,0,0)
    gun = Gun(screen)   

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        gun.output()
        pygame.display.flip()

run()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @Minsy если вам нетрудно, отметьте мой ответ, как правильный, пожалуйста)